# Using REQUIRES_NEW JTA transaction type in MyBatis on Wildfly

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly, mybatis, jta

I am trying to use mybatis-cdi within Wildfly and I need to run part of method in separate transaction - see following snippet:

```java
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ItemService {

    @Inject
    @Mapper
    ItemMapper mapper;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomething() {
        List<Item> items = mapper.findByTime(new Date());
        for(Item i : items) {
            update(i);
        }
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void update(Item item) {
        mapper.updateSomehow(item);
    }
}
```

Is this correct way how to do it? Is this supported with mybatis-cdi, or should it be done some different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting your expected behavior as interceptors are not applied when using a self reference in a method, for example how `doSomething()` calls `update()` directly.  You would need that to occur in a separate bean to allow a separate transaction interaction.

Comment: Thanks, found it in between by myself: https://github.com/dlee0113/java_ee_patterns_and_best_practices/blob/master/SelfInvokingEJB/src/java/com/abien/patterns/business/selfinvocation/Hack.java

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your EJB into itself in order to call it through the proxy:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
class ItemService {

    @Inject
    @Mapper
    private ItemMapper mapper;

    @Inject // or @EJB
    private ItemService itemService;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomething() {
        List<Item> items = mapper.findByTime(new Date());
        for (Item i : items) {
            itemService.update(i); // here's the trick
        }
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void update(Item item) {
        mapper.updateSomehow(item);
    }
}
```